# Conditional formatting with Multiple Conditions (Now function and another Blank cell)

Tags: excel

I need to add conditional formatting to a column based on two conditions:

1. If the cells in this column contain a date that is earlier than the current date (column G is the one that needs formatting and contains the dates)
2. If a particular cell in another column is blank (column L is the one with the cells that may/may not be blank)

I tried `=AND($G$3>NOW(),ISBLANK($L$3))` but I can't get it to work.

Comment: The short answer might be =AND($G$3<NOW(),ISBLANK($L$3)) but we could do with some examples to test it on

Comment: Use `today()` instead of `now()`